# create an addhandler with arguments to the handler

Tags: vb.net, addhandler

I have a C# line of code I want to translate to VB.net
It is:

```
job.StateChanged += new  EventHandler<JobStateChangedEventArgs>(StateChanged);
```

I know how to do this:

```
 AddHandler job.StateChanged, AddressOf StateChanged
```

But that seems to leave out the type of argument (JobStateChangedEventArgs) that C# is able to express.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: But `job.StateChanged` provides the `JobStateChangedEventArgs` when the event is raised. `StateChanged` is just the event handler.

Comment: I don't see the exact point of the original C# code. The most logical version would be: `job.StateChanged += new EventHandler(StateChanged);`. Other thing is declaring an event: `event EventHandler<JobStateChangedEventArgs> myEvent;` and then using it in the assignation: `job.StateChanged += myEvent;`. If you do everything in "one go", you don't need the `<JobStateChangedEventArgs>` bit (for what? You can only attach to `.StateChanged` the supported event). Same thing for `AddressOf` (with `Option Strict On`): you can attach only the right event and thus this bit is not necessary.